# How to prove absolute and total convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\pi^{nx}}{\pi^{nx^2}+\sqrt{n}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, pi

Consider the series of functions
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\pi^{nx}}{\pi^{nx^2}+\sqrt{n}}, \qquad x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

I want to study for which $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the series converges.

I start studying the absolute convergence. Taking $|f_n(x)| =\frac{\pi^{nx}}{\pi^{nx^2}+\sqrt{n}}$, the necessary condition for the convergence is satisfied if
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\pi^{nx}}{\pi^{nx^2}+\sqrt{n}}\sim \lim_{n\to +\infty} \pi^{n(x-x^2)}=0 \iff x-x^2<0,$$
i.e. the series could converge if $x<0\cup x>1$.

${\bf EDIT:}$ In order to study the absolute convergence, I use the comparison. Thus, having that $\pi^{nx^2}+\sqrt{n}\ge \pi^{nx^2}$, we obtain that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\pi^{nx}}{\pi^{nx^2}+\sqrt{n}}\le \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\pi^{n(x-x^2)}$$
which does converge for $x<0\cup x>1$. Anyway, it is also true that $\pi^{nx^2}+\sqrt{n}\ge \sqrt{n}$ so that we could apply the comparison test in this way
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\pi^{nx}}{\pi^{nx^2}+\sqrt{n}}\le \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\pi^{nx}}{\sqrt{n}}\sim\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\pi^{nx}$$
which does converge for $x<0$. As you see, the sets of convergence are different according to the different choices one make.

My question is: what is the correct answer? In which of the two set we obtain the absolute convergence?

Finally, I am in trouble also with total convergence.

${\bf 2nd EDIT}$:
I start studying the total convergence when $x<0$. It is
$$\sup_{x<0} \left\vert\frac{\pi^{nx}}{\pi^{nx^2}+\sqrt{n}}\right\vert =\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}}$$
and the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}}$$
diverges, so we have no total convergence in $(-\infty, 0)$.
Thus, I proceed studying the convergence in the compact subsets $(1, a]\subset (1, +\infty)$. It is

$$\sup_{x\in (1, a]} \left\vert\frac{\pi^{nx}}{\pi^{nx^2}+\sqrt{n}}\right\vert= \frac{\pi^{na}}{\pi^{na^2}+\sqrt{n}}$$

and the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\pi^{na}}{\pi^{na^2}+\sqrt{n}}$$

does converge. Could anyone please tell me if my resoning is correct?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Note $\sum\frac{\pi^{nx}}{\pi^{nx^2}}$ converges _if_ $x>0$. So the original converges for $x>0$. The sentence "but...which diverges" is simply irrelevant: Assuming $0\le a_n\le b_n$ and $\sum b_n=\infty$ says nothing whatever about $\sum a_n$. (The series $\sum\frac{\pi^{nx}}{\sqrt n}$ does converge for $x<0$, hence the original converges for $x<0$.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich why $\sum\frac{\pi^{nx}}{\pi^{nx^2}}$ converges for $x>0$? We have $\sum\frac{\pi^{nx}}{\pi^{nx^2}}=\sum\left(\frac{1}{\pi^{x^2-x}}\right)^n$ (geometric series) which converge for $|\pi^{x-x^2}|<1$, isn't it? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Anyway, we can use the comparison test with two different series which converge in different sets. What we can say about the convergence of the original series? It converges in the smallest set between them? I hope you could help, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you mapped out two alternatives to dominate your original series with a convergent one.

1. The absolute value of the denominator of the original series is larger than one for $n\geq1$. Then, you may use $\sum_n\pi^{nx}$ as a comparator, you get a  geometric series  ($z=\pi^x$) which can be seen to converge for $x<0$ (uniform convergent in compact subsets of $(-\infty,0)$
2. The absolute of the denominator of the original series is larger than $\pi^{nx^2}$ you use $\sum_n\pi^{n(x-x^2)}$ as a comparator, this is again a geometric series ($z=\pi^{x-x^2}$) which converges  if $\pi^{x-x^2} <1$. Thus, you get convergence for $x\in (-\infty,0)\cup(1,\infty)=U$ (uniform convergence in compact subsets of $U$).

The second option gives you a larger domain of convergence.

Alternatively, since the expressions are not very complicated, you may also try to use a convergence test, such as the ratio test, on the original series. Since $\pi^{x^2}>1$ for all $x\neq0$
$$\frac{\frac{\pi^{(n+1)x}}{\pi^{(n+1)x^2}+\sqrt{n+1}}}{\frac{\pi^{nx}}{\pi^{nx^2}+\sqrt{n}}}=\frac{\pi^{nx^2}+\sqrt{n}}{\pi^{(n+1)x^2}+\sqrt{n+1}}\pi^x\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\pi^{x-x^2}.\qquad x\neq0$$
which gives you converges for all $x$ fir which $\pi^{x-x^2}<1$ (same as in (2)).

Comment: It is exactly what I did. Thank you for the answer, but I don't understand well. What is the correct interval of convergence, U or $(-\infty, 0)$? It seems you choose the larger. In general, if I am able to compare with two different series with different sets of convergence (as in this case), what should I take?

Comment: @C.Bishop $U=(-\infty,0)\cup(1,\infty)$ is the best domain of convergence. It follows directly from the test root. If you recall, for any series $\sum_nf_n(z)$ converges for all $z$ such that $\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|f_n(z)|}<1$ and diverges for all $z$ such that $\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|f_n(z)|}>1$. When the ratio test works, so does the root test and the domain of convergence coincide.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please have a lokk to my attempt with total convergence? Thank you in advance.